# ElasticPress does not search for substrings

Tags: wordpress, elasticsearch, elasticpress

As the title states I have a problem that ElasticPress does not search for substrings within ACFs.

I am currently using ElasticSearch version 7.10.1 and ElasticPress version 4.7.0.

For example if I'm searching for `MySubstring` it will only find results where the whole word `MySubstring` is matched but not `SomethingAtTheStartMySubstring`, `MySubstringSomethingAtTheEnd`, `SomethingAtTheStartMySubstringSomethingAtTheEnd`.

[This post](https://elasticpress.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/16671887174541-Indexables) suggests that a fuzzy search is executed by default.
[image]

The search itself is working for whole words, but as I said not for substrings.

I've already tried to search for a solution but couldn't find any solution.

Thank you guys in advance.

Comment: Not sure what your setup looks like, but you essentially need to set the `compare` for the `meta_query` to `LIKE`, default I believe is `=`, which is why your fuzzy search isn't working: https://github.com/10up/ElasticPress/issues/1863#issuecomment-734317783

Comment: @disinfor according to the post I've mentioned above the fuzzy search is done by default. My problem with using a LIKE query is that I don't know all meta fields, because I'm using lots of repeaters and they are stored within the postmeta table like repeatername_1_fieldname, repeatername_2_fieldname, etc.

Comment: Yes, it says fuzzy search is done by default, but it appears not to be hence the github issue. The repeaters, since there may be more or less `meta_keys` depending on the post, You may want to consider saving all the data in the repeaters for each post into a single meta value that you can reference for ElasticSearch.